# File download: href not working. Browser security blocks from redirecting to the url.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to download a file(could be of any type) from server. And the url is of type file://url@domain.com/... My Front end is Worklight and I'm using a wcf service to connect to database. Using a simple href at the worklight end doesn't work due to browser security. Please help me with this. Or suggest an alternate method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Cordova File API to download and store files in your mobile application. Refer to the Cordova documentation and ask again if you encounter a programming issue.